# Specific app pinned always disappears from start Win 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I have already tried TDLrecover, did not help. So I have this program Cemu which did not make its own shortcut in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` so I made a shortcut in programs. The start tile (when pinned is fully usable but will disappear after:

- Restarting, Shutting Down, Hibernating and Sleeping Win10
- Opening the program
- Making a new shortcut in \programs or installing something new

It only happens to this one program, and does not happen to others. Also under recently added it is ALWAYS at the top of the list, even after installing new programs.

Comment: It might be that your antivirus has something against it.

Comment: No antivirus, defender does not detect it. It is an emulator.

Comment: Try to turn off Defender real time protection - files do not disappear without reason.

Comment: Already tried turning off defender, didn't make a difference

Comment: You could use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to trace and find the program that deletes this shortcut.

Comment: Does changing the shortcut to Read-Only help?